# What should I use as a hash code of null?

Tags: java, hash, null, hashcode, hash-collision

Assume we have a following trivial class:

```
public class Foo {

    public Integer bar;

}
```

And we want to build a "good" `hashCode` method for it. By "good" I would, for instance mean that there's a small probability of hash code collision in "real-life" cases.

In "real-life" for such a class I would reasonably expect `Foo`s with `bar` set to `null` or `0`. I'd even argue that these two are probably the most frequent values.

But let's take a look at what Eclipse, for instance, generates:

```
public class Foo {

    public Integer bar;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((bar == null) ? 0 : bar.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

And it's not just Eclipse, it seems like using `0` as `hashCode` for `null` is a normal practice.

But this would produce identical hash codes for `null` and `0`, wouldn't it? An as I'm assuming that `null` and `0` are probably the most frequent cases - this leads to a higher probabiliy of collission.

So here comes my question. **What would be a good `hashCode` value for `null`?**

Comment: @SarthakMittal Which one?

Comment: can your bar.hashCode() return negative value? if not then any negative value would suffice otherwise i would suggest to use Integer.MIN_VALUE :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal Yes, sure it can. It's just some integer...

Comment: Then what do you say about Integer.MIN_VALUE ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Joshua Bloch's excellent book *Effective Java, 2nd Edition* (page 49):

> If the value of the field is `null`, return `0` (or some other constant, but `0` is traditional).

So you can use any constant of your choice, but usually, `0` is used as the hash code of `null`.

In your case, where 0 appear frequently, it might indeed be better to choose a different constant than 0 (one that doesn't appear as a valid value in your field) to avoid collisions.

Comment: I know this is traditional, was always doing it myself. But now I question the tradition.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a constant which doesn't appear often might be difficult. You can use a `negative constant` to avoid conflict with null.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with whatever Eclipse produces, or `0`.

If testing or profiling shows that changing the hash code for null would improve performance, go for it. Change it to any arbritrary constant.

Comment: We are currently writing a code generator which creates `hashCode`. in the generated classes.

Comment: I see! Well, `0` seems fine to me. If you really want to avoid collisions for that very simple example class, the only other option is to pick some number other than 0. KISS. Keep it simple until you have a good reason not to.